# Not works correctly hang up (webRTC) and not works do again a call

Tags: video, coffeescript, webrtc

I am implementing a videoconferencing with webrtc. I have done it, with hang up button, but when I push this button and I call again, videoconference does not work well.

The connection is done because I see it, but the remote's camera don't turn on. And sometimes is appeared this message: "createAnswer can not be called before SetRemoteDescription.". But in the first time never appeared.

This is the code of hangup in client (in coffeeScript):

```
@localStream.stop() if @localStream
@remoteVideo.stop()
@localVideo.stop()
```

I don't know why when I do call again after doing hangup, this call doesn't work.

```
join: (video=true, friend) =>
    parse_friend =
      id       : friend?.id
      username : friend?.username
      mail     : friend?.mail
      avatar   : friend?.avatar
    session = JSON.parse localStorage.getItem KEY
    SOCKET.emit 'join', session.access_token, video, parse_friend
    SOCKET.on 'ready', @readyToCall
    SOCKET.on 'offer', @onOffer

 token: =>
    SOCKET.on 'token', @onToken @createOffer
    SOCKET.emit 'token'



 onToken: (callback) =>
        (token) =>
          @peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection iceServers: configuration.iceServers
          @peerConnection.addStream @localStream
          @peerConnection.onicecandidate = @onIceCandidate
          @peerConnection.onaddstream = @onAddStream
          SOCKET.on 'candidate', @onCandidate
          SOCKET.on 'answer', @onAnswer
          callback()
          return




hangUp: (friend) =>
    session = JSON.parse localStorage.getItem KEY
    @localStream.stop() if @localStream
    SOCKET.emit 'hangUp', session.id, friend

onFinish: (value) =>
    @localStream.stop() if @localStream
    if @peerConnection then @peerConnection.close()
    @trigger 'finish', value
```

Comment: That's too vague to answer. Perhaps you're not doing enough clean up and some of your code is not reset correctly. This is impossible to say without seeing *all* of your code (but please don't post all). It's not a fundamental problem with WebRTC as such, that's for sure.

Comment: You'll have to show more of your code. This is not enough to determine a problem.